# How to know if a string length contains a specified amount of capped letters

Tags: c#, discord.net

I'm trying to know if a string contains a length between 5 and 10 and at the same time, 7-10 letters are in upper case. The idea is to detect if a message sent by a user is 70%-100% capped.

This is what I have tried so far:

```cs
bool IsMessageUpper(string input)
{
    if (input.Length.Equals(5 <= 10) && (input.Take(7).All(c => char.IsLetter(c) && char.IsUpper(c))))
    {
         return true;
    }
    else
    {
         return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of taking the first seven characters and seeing they are all uppercase, count the number of uppercase letters.  `input.Count(Char.IsUpper)`

Comment: How can a string have a length of 5 while containing 7 upper case characters? Somethings wrong in the logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rewrite your method in this way

```
bool IsMessageUpper(string input)
{
    int x = input.Length;
    return x>=7 && x<= 10 && input.Count(char.IsUpper) >= 7;
}
```

You can also add some safety checks to handle undesidered inputs

```
bool IsMessageUpper(string input)
{
    int x = (input ?? "").Length;
    return x>=7 && x<= 10 && input.Count(char.IsUpper) >= 7;
}
```

Comment: Drop the `x>=5` check, it is doing nothing, or change it to `x>=7` if you want to prevent calling `input.Count` too much.